# how to save state of .net windows service after stopping and start from this state

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, service, state

We would like to realize some specific idea in our system of saving state of windows services.

During updating our system we are stopping windows services, which are making different operations, some of them for a long time  (few days). Some time we are making dump of memory for specific service for understanding what objects are using RAM.

My question is: is there any way or technology to start service after stopping from some specific state, which was saved previosly in memory dump?

Thank you very much for your answers.

Comment: (De-)Serialization of state?

Comment: Yes, something like that. Serialization of state for service.

Comment: Thats the solution, the implementation of this solution will differ based on your runtime environment. Basically serialize all state object to disk on "OnStop", check if there is a state to deserialize in "OnStart".

Comment: Have a look at "BinaryFormatter", "XmlSerializer" and "DataContractSerializer" for serialization engines in .Net

Comment: What do you mean about environment? Is it based on some specific thing s or configurations in operation system?

Comment: There are multiple ways to serialize objects; into different target format and onto different target surfaces. My guess based on info provided so far would be "Use binary serialization onto a file system/database".